# jquery, divs with prev and next to show up with slideDown effect

Tags: jquery, slidedown

HTML:

A few `divs` with next and prev `divs` inside to navigate forward and backward. On clicking a certain next  div , the  following div should be visible with slideDown effect. But that does not actually happen. Code follows:

```
<div class="q_group" id="q_group_1">

    <div class="prev_next">

        <div class="next" target_div="q_group_2" >Next</div>
    </div>  
</div>

<div class="q_group invisible" id="q_group_2">

    <div class="prev_next">

    <div class="prev" target_div="q_group_1" >Prev</div>
    <div class="next" target_div="q_group_3" >Next</div>

   </div>   

</div>

 <div class="q_group invisible" id="q_group_3">

        <div class="prev_next">

           <div class="prev" target_div="q_group_2" >Prev</div>

    </div>  

 </div>
```

CSS:

```
<style type="text/css">

#q_group_1{

    background-color: green;
}
#q_group_2{

    background-color: red;
}

#q_group_3{

    background-color: yellow;
}

.q_group{

    width: 300px;
    height: 200px;
}

.invisible{
    display: none;
}

.prev,.next{
    width: 60px;
    background-color: green;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    cursor: pointer;


}

.prev{
    float: left;
}

.next{
    float: right;
}

</style>
```

Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){


$(document).on('click','.next, .prev',function(){


    $elem = $(this);

    var target_div = $elem.attr('target_div');

    $elem.slideUp('slow',function(){

    $("#"+target_div).slideDown().children().show();    

    });




});

});
```

How to achieve the expected function ?

EDIT: js fiddel [here](http://jsfiddle.net/jsf_user/SS7KJ/)

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(document).on('click', '.next, .prev', function () {
        $elem = $(this);
        var target_div = $elem.attr('target_div');
        $elem.closest('.q_group').stop(true, true).slideUp('slow', function () {
            $("#" + target_div).stop(true, true).slideDown();
        });
    });
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/PA3D4/)

Comment: where is the fiddle address ?

Answer (score 0):

Your code is absolutely right only thing you are doing is slideUp the next/prev div instead whole div. Corrected code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){


  $(document).on('click','.next, .prev',function(){


    $elem = $(this);

    paren=$(this).parent().parent();

    var target_div = $elem.attr('target_div');

    paren.slideUp('slow',function(){

    $("#"+target_div).slideDown().children().show();    

    });

  });

});
```

Demo: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/prakashdbhagat/9EL9U/)